# Convergence of sequences such as $ B(n)=1/\sqrt{n^2+1}+\dots+ n/\sqrt{n^2+n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Examine the following arithmetic  sequences if they converge or do not.The first one is  $$ B(n)=1/\sqrt{n^2+1}+\dots+ n/\sqrt{n^2+n}$$ and the second $$C(n)=n/(n^2+1)+\dots+n/(n^2+n)$$
It was on our exams.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 1/\sqrt{n^2+1}+\dots+ n/\sqrt{n^2+n} \ge \dfrac{1 + 2 + ... + n}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} = \dfrac{n(n+ 1)}{2\sqrt{n^2 + n}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{n^2 + n}}{2} \ge \dfrac n 2 \to \infty$$

Hence the sequence $B(n)$ diverges.

Now for the second sequence,

$$ \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{n}} =  n \cdot \dfrac{n}{n^2 + n}  \le n/(n^2+1)+\dots+n/(n^2+n) \le n \cdot\dfrac{ n }{n^2 + 1} = \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2}}  $$

Note that both left and right approximations converge to $1$. Hence by the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) $C(n) \to 1$.

*Credit to Silynn for pointing out the errors.*

Comment: Isn't the Cauchy Criterion for series not infinite sequences?

Comment: @Silynn: Of course there is a Cauchy criterion for sequences. But they are just called Cauchy sequences. And I posted the wrong link. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much i mostly consider cauchy criterion a bit diffycult but it was not actually

Comment: I think you might have made a mistake for $C(n)$, because can't that be written as $n\left(\psi(1+n+n^2)-\psi(1+n^2)\right)$ which converges to 1?

Comment: @Silynn: No seems legit to me. Lemme know if you find an issue with the solution. And I'm afraid I don't know the $\psi $ notation you use. Over my head.

Comment: Digamma function. But the only issue I'm finding is the $n^2$ terms in the denomination should be $4n^2$ for the $2n$ terms, but not sure how that affects it. It looks good, so I don't know what's wrong with my expression.

Comment: @Ishfaaq using cauchy criterion most times helps i take $2n$ sub-sequence or generaly a multyple of n?

Comment: @Silynn: Youre dead right. Edited. Corrected

Comment: @Manolis Lyviakis well the point is to show that "given any $N \in \Bbb N$ there are two natural numbers $m, n \in \Bbb N$ such that $ m, n \ge N$ and $|m - n| \ge \epsilon $ for some fixed positive value $\epsilon$. So the easiest thing to do is to find a multiple of $N$ or $2N$ as our $m$ and $n = N$ so that there is always a corresponding pair for any choice of $N$". Won't always work though. Also I made a mistake in the second sequence. SO note the edits.

Comment: @Ishfaaq     isnt the $4n^2$ also on the first sequence?